# How do I center text in a page heading?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer

I'm using `\markright` to create a page heading.  I'm having trouble centering some text in this heading, and I'd like to know how to do this.

Here's my current setup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\TitleString}{This Is The Title}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\markright{\TitleString \hfill Matt Groff \hfill}

Title and copyright are above.

\end{document}
```

I use `\hfill` to fill in the space so that my name is close to centered, but for large titles it's way off.  Is there a way to fix this?  I'd like my name to be completely centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified variant of Geoffrey's solution that avoids `\protect` and the doubling of `\TitleString`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\TitleString}{This Is A Rather Long Title}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\markright{\rlap{\TitleString}\hfill Matt Groff\hfill}

Title and copyright are above.

\end{document}
```

(Note that there are no spaces before the `\hfill`!)

Explanation: `\rlap` writes the text but just "overlaps it to the right" without it taking up any space.

Answer (score 7):

Use `\phantom` to "balance" your title line, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}  % <-- help to see what's going on

\newcommand{\TitleString}{This Is A Rather Long Title}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\markright{\TitleString \hfill%
            Matt Groff%
            \hfill\protect\phantom{\TitleString}}

Title and copyright are above.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent!  By the way, do you know why it puts everything in italics (or emphasis)?

Comment: @Matt Groff: sure - if you look in the definitions of the oneside and twoside header macros in article.cls (`\ps@headings`), you'll see that it applies `\slshape` to the header output stream (this sometimes maps to `\itshape` in some font families). All you need do to modify your header formatting is to change your invocation of `\markright`, e.g., to `\markright{\textnormal{\TitleString ... }}`.

Comment: @Matt: Note the `%` after your name in Geoffrey's solution. This is important since otherwise there'll be an unwanted space after the name, and it won't be exactly centered.

Answer (score 5):

My usual choice would be the [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{This is a title}
\chead{Mark Groff}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0.0 pt}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `scrpage2` package which is part of [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\TitleString}{This Is The Title}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{\TitleString}% Inner head 
\chead{Matt Groff}

\begin{document}

Title and copyright are above.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That'll do it.  Thanks!  I'm surprised that it requires a package, for something so simple.

Comment: The LaTeX2e kernel is well known for being rather inflexible on formatting, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

Obligatory ConTeXt solution:

```
\setupheadertexts[Mark Groff]     % Center
\setupheadertexts[\TitleString][] % Left  Right
```